# qt web oauth 2.0 webview redirection bigquery

Tags: qt, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, qwebview

I'm trying to use this application: http://code.google.com/p/qt-google-bigquery/
to make google bigquery authorization via web on cross platform, getting access token from the callback url, but the qt webview component doesn't seem to redirect after clicking "allow access" on the web page. I've searched for similar issues on the internet and ive found out that this is maybe caused by ssl although i'm sceptical about the sollution to rebuild qt with openssl since the page i'm opening first of all is also ssl (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?) and it works just fine. I assume there is something else to be dealt with. I also tried enabling javascript for the webview but it didn't help. Any ideas out there to solve the issue?

Comment: The source code uses the Google Books API scope and not the BigQuery Scope: http://code.google.com/p/qt-google-bigquery/source/browse/oauth2.cpp#11

Which redirect URI are you using? And what OAuth flow? (http://code.google.com/p/qt-google-bigquery/source/browse/oauth2.cpp#13)

Comment: Let me please humbly state that my problem has nothing to do with the scope or the redirect url, or the flow:
My problem is that in the sample Qt application i've linked there the embedded Qtwebview stays in blocked state after clicking allowing access (if i copy the current url to chrome or something else, redirecting works just fine and i get my access token in the url)

Although now i've made a fix to this by using a small tcpserver and QDesktopServices::openUrl()+code flow still i'd like to know why Qtwebview is not redirecting.

Thanks for your kind intention to help me